# Printing a message from a base class function through the operator <<

Tags: c++, visual-c++

This is the header file with class `Rectangle` that inherits from class `Shape`:

```
class Rectangle: public Shape {

  private:
    double width;
    double height;

  protected:

    // overrides the base class's toString implementation.
    // returns a string representation of the class. The method returns the value of id, name, width, height separated by an @:
    // <<value of id>>@<<value of name>>@<<value of width>>@<<value of height>>
    // note that you must reuse the base class's toString implementation. Don't repeat code from the base class
    string toString() const;
```

Now this is a an `operator<<` from class `Rectangle`:

```
// Overloads the standard output stream operator to print the message from toString() to the standard output stream
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const Rectangle *rectangle);
```

This is my code for the `Rectangle.cpp`:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Rectangle* rectangle) {
    os << *rectangle.toString();
    return os;
}
```

It's telling me that the expression must have a class type. Please help.

BTW, this is the `toString()` function that I declared in the `Rectangle.cpp`:

```
string Rectangle::toString() const {
    return to_string(this->id) + "@" + this->name + "@" + to_string(this->width) + to_string(this->height);
}
```

Comment: Change the second parameter of the overloaded `operator<<` to `const Rectangle&` instead of a `const Rectangle *`.

Comment: The reason for the error is that, due to rules of operator precedence, `*rectangle.toString()` is equivalent to `*(rectangle.toString())` not (as you seem to expect) to `(*rectangle).toString()`.    Either (1) change the `operator<<()` so it accepts a `const` reference (instead of a pointer) and remove the `*` from `*rectangle.toString()`.   OR  (2)  output `rectangle->toString()` or (equivalently) `(*rectangle).toString()`.

Comment: FYI, when dealing with `operator<<` for polymorphic classes, the operator should be defined for the base class, not the derived classes, and then it should call a virtual method that derived classes override. You have the 2nd part correct, but not the 1st part.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you've made the second parameter of the overloaded `operator<<` to be a pointer(`const Rectangle *`) whereas it should be a *reference*(`const Rectangle &`) as shown below. Note that this is a problem because due to [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) the expression `*rectangle.toString()` is equivalent to:

```
*(rectangle.toString())  //equivalent to this because of operator precedence
```

But the above can't work as `rectangle` is a pointer type.

Additionally, you were missing a low-level `const` in the second parameter of the overloaded `operator<<` while defining it. This is also fixed in the below shown demo.

---

##### Solution

There are two ways to solve this. You can either make the second parameter a `const Rectangle&` or change the expression `*rectangle.toString()` to `rectangle->toString()`.

**Method 1**

```
class Rectangle{
//------------------------------------------------------v------------>note the lvalue reference
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const Rectangle &rectangle);

//other code here
}
//------------------------------vvvvv-----------v--------------->const and & added here
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,const  Rectangle& rectangle) {
    os << rectangle.toString();
//-------^------------------------>removed the * from here
    return os;

}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/iebAorOIe)

---

**Method 2**

```
//------------------------------vvvvv-------------------------->const added here
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,const Rectangle* rectangle) {
    os << rectangle->toString();
//-----------------^^--------------->  here we have used ->
    return os;
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/kAv3N-uA6)